# Builder vs Factory Design Pattern in specific code

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory, builder

I would like to ask what is better to use, factory or builder design pattern, in my case.

Long story short, I have class Action with parameters: transferRate, recoverRate, cost and name.

In my program, I will have array with 30 (always same) Action objects. Every has always same setup of parameters.

I am thinking more about using factory but if you give me advice which is better, I would appreciate that.

Short example:

```
import lombok.Getter;
```

Factory:

```
@Getter
abstract public class Action {
    protected double transferRateBlock;
    protected double recoverRateBlock;
    protected int cost;
    protected String name;
}

public class CloseAirports extends Action {
    public CloseAirports(){
        this.transferRateBlock = -0.4;
        this.recoverRateBlock = 0;
        this.cost = 3;
        this.name = "Close airports";
    }
}

public class CloseBorders extends Action {
    public CloseBorders(){
        this.transferRateBlock = -0.5;
        this.recoverRateBlock = 0;
        this.cost = 4;
        this.name = "Close Borders";
    }
}
```

I have 30 subclasses like that. Every subclass is going to array in another class. Client is just using these actions, never create any. Every is always precreatted.

```
CloseAirports closeAirports = new CloseAirports();
CloseBorders closeBorders = new CloseBorders();
Action[] allActions = {closeAirports, closeBorders};
```

Or should i use rather Builder Design Pattern with this implementation ? :

```
Action closeSchool = new Action().withTransferRateBlock(0.5).withRecoverRateBlock(0).withCost(2).withName("Close Schools");
Action[] allActions = {closeSchool};
```

Comment: Facade and Builder have nothing to do with each other. They don't serve the same purpose. so, why exactly do you think you should 'choose' between these two?

Comment: Okey, I am so sorry, i have made a mistake. I wanted to compare Builder and Factory design pattern. My fault....If is it possible to change the name of question will do it.

Comment: those two also serve different purposes. There's no problem in implementing them both. Honestly, I don't see more than one type in your explanation, so I have no idea why you would even consider a Factory pattern.

Comment: Because when i create array of Action objects, i think it looks cleaner.

Short example:
Factory:
'CloseShops closeShops = new CloseShops();'
'CloseAirports closeAirports = new CloseAirports();'

and next 30 objects of 30 classes which are just extending Action and have setted Up parameters of action.

'Action[] allActions = {closeShops, closeAirports, ... };'

Builder:
'Action  closeShops = new' 'Action().withTransferRate(0).withRecoveryRate(0.1).withName("close airports").withCost(3).build();'

And do it again 30 times more and add everithing to array.

Comment: that is really unreadable. Can you edit that in your question as formatted code?

Comment: sorry for that. i wasnt able to edit it in comment (i dont know how) so i have added that to original question in formated block.

Comment: Your Factory example has nothing to do with the Factory pattern. Your Builder example won't compile, since you have a ; between new and your classname, it's also incorrectly implemented.

Comment: Yes i know that ; was just mistake during copy. Okey if thats not factory design pattern (doesnt matter how is it called), which way from these two examples whould you recommend ?

Comment: but now i am pretty much sure that first example ist factory...

Comment: the first example isn't factory, it's just ... normal instantiation, it's not a design pattern at all. You want me to recommend one of two unrelated design patterns? I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, I do know, however, you don't know the design patterns you want to choose between. If you don't know them, you 'll likely not know what their purpose is and why/how to use them. So best: don't use any, until you know what they do, and how they (are supposed to) do it.

Comment: yes it is factory....most common example on internet i found is 
"abstract class Shape",
"class Circle extends Shape",
"class Rectangle extends Shape"

thats the same as my first example....

Comment: okey never mind....thank you for trying to help

Comment: I looked at your examples, that is not what you are doing. 
I'll give you a link to an example of both: 
Factory: https://www.baeldung.com/java-abstract-factory-pattern   Builder: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/DesignPatternBuilder/article.html

Comment: I know these links. And yes i do it there but propably i describe it bad when you cant see it there...sorry

Comment: You mean CloseShops and CloseAirports are subclasses of Action?

Comment: Yes, thats what i meant by that text under code that these classes extend Action. "extends" is java syntax so sorry for bad interpretation of describing that.

Comment: @MatejPeluha Why don't you show the relevant code so you won't have to explain what it looks like?

Comment: Yes, you are right...my fault...i change it....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factory example:

```
public class ActionFactory implements AbstractFactory<Action>{

  @Override
  public Action createAction(int type) {
    switch(type) {
      case 1: return new CloseShops();
      case 2: return new CloseAirports();
      default: return null;
  }

}
```

So, if you would want to differentiate between the types, and avoid having the developer himself building the objects, this is what to use. He can still pass additional parameters to the createAction method.

```
List<Action> myActions = new ArrayList<>();
ActionFactory fact = new ActionFactory();
for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
  int type = assumeThisReadIntMethodExists();
  myActions.add(fact.createAction(type)); // this will add CloseShops or CloseAirports depending on the type passed
}
```

Builder example:
The Builder pattern is more to avoid problems while creating instances. For example, for missing information.

```
public class CloseShops {
  private final String nameOfShop;

  private CloseShops(String name) {
    this.nameOfShop = name; // as you can see, no check for null
    // it's always better to check for null before starting a constructor
  }

  public String getNameOfShop() {
    return nameOfShop;
  }
  // additional methods

  public static class Builder {
    private String name;

    public Builder withName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
      return this;
    }

    public Builder fromCloseShops(CloseShops original) {
      this.name = original.getNameOfShop();
      return this;
    }

    public CloseShops build() {
      assertNotNull("The name is mandatory", name);
      // this assert to avoid calling the constructor if the name is null
      return new CloseShops(this.name);
    }
}
```

This can be called like this:

```
Action b = new CloseShops.Builder().withName("shopName").build();
```

So, if it's to have less code, go for Factory.

Comment: Thank you, i lso again edited my question with more specific example o factory in my code. Thank you also for this.

By the way client is never creating any of that objects. All of these subclasses of Action must be in one array and client is just choosing which turnOn and which turnOff.

Thank you very much i will go for Factory.